# Dynamodb2 Table Schema Creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using the following: dynamodb2, boto, python. I have the following code for creating a table:

```
table = Table.create('mySecondTable', 
schema=[HashKey('ID')],
RangeKey('advertiser'),
throughput={'read':5,'write':2},
global_indexes=[GlobalAllIndex('otherDataIndex',parts=[
    HashKey('date',data_type=NUMBER),
    RangeKey('publisher', date_type=str),
],throughput={'read':5,'write':3})], 
connection=conn)
```

I would like to be able to have the following data that I can query by:
ID, advertiser, date, publisher, size, and color

That means I need a different schema. When I add additional points it does not query unless the column name is listed in the schema.

The problem however is that right now I am only able to query by Id, advertiser, date, and publisher in this case. How can I add additional columns that I can query by?

I read this which appears to say that it is possible:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

However there is no example here:
http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dynamodb2_tut.html

I tried adding an additional range key however it doesn't work (cannot have duplicates)

I'd like it to be like:

```
table = Table.create('mySecondTable', 
schema=[
RangeKey('advertiser'),
otherKey('date')
fourthKey('publisher') ... etc
throughput={'read':5,'write':2},
connection=conn)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add additional range keys you need to use [Local secondary index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html).

You can query the LSI in the same way that you query the base table. You need to provide an exact value for the hashkey and a comparison-predicate for range key.